# Any way to check that package.json engines satisfies version of global installed packages/binaries?

Tags: npm, package.json

As I understand, the engines object is only for cases where someone installs my application. I would like to have something similar where I can prevent compiling errors on employee systems (because of wrong node versions etc.) before they happen.

I found that there are two packages:

- https://github.com/jgillich/npm-check-engines/blob/master/index.js
- https://github.com/kruppel/check-engines

But they are not working or not doing what I want.

It would be nice to have a script running before `npm install` that checks these engines versions and if they are available in path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a package that does this.

https://github.com/muuvmuuv/npm-supervisor

It can be run via npm before installation and will check if a version in engines satisfies the global or local installed version.